# How to format table output into list format using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-table

I have a table that I am appending to an html element on my website. However, it gets appended as a single line list in the format: ['element1', 'element2', ...].

Is it possible to change the formatting to look more like:

1. element1
2. element2
3. ....

The following is my js function which processes a csv file I am pulling the data from to make the table.

```
function submitForm(){
    nameValue = document.getElementById("searchTerm").value;
    //bug: takes 2 presses to display results initially

    //capitalize each letter of a new word
    nameValue = nameValue.replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s+\w{1})/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase());

    document.getElementById("display-results").innerHTML = nameValue;
    location.href = "#page-3";
    
    //todo: seperate games into list + hyperlink 
    function arrayToTable(tableData) {
        var table = $('<table></table>');
        $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
            var row = $('<tr></tr>');
            $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
              if (cellData == nameValue) {
                row.append($('<td>'+rowData[1]+'</td>'));
              }
            });
            table.append(row);
        });
        return table;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "mainFile.csv",
        success: function (data) {
            if($('#display-results table').length === 0) // append if you haven't built the table yet
                $('#display-results').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
            else
                $('#display-results table').replaceWith(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `.each()` designed for elements. You would want to use `$.each()` for Arrays and Objects.

Comment: @Twisty I'm still a bit confused where to use `.each()`. Would I call it upon `(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data))).each()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following. This is untested as you did not provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```js
$(function() {
  function arrayToTable(tableData, name) {
    if (tableData == undefined || name == undefined) {
      return $("<table>");
    }
    var table = $('<table>');
    $.each(tableData, function(i, rows) {
      var row = $('<tr>').appendTo(table);
      $.each(rows, function(j, cell) {
        if (cell == name) {
          $("<td>").html(cell).appendTo(row);
        }
      });
    });
    return table;
  }

  function firstToCap(txt) {
    return txt.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1);
  }

  function getCSV(url, target) {
    if (url == undefined) {
      return false;
    }
    if (target == undefined) {
      target = "body";
    }
    // https://www.papaparse.com/#remote-files
    Papa.parse(url, {
      download: true,
      complete: function(results) {
        $(target).append(arrayToTable(results));
      }
    });
  }

  function submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var nameValue = firstToCap($("#searchTerm").val());

    $("#display-results").html(nameValue);
    location.href = "#page-3";

    getCSV("mainFile.csv", "#display-results");
  }

  $("form").submit(submitForm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.2/papaparse.min.js" integrity="sha512-SGWgwwRA8xZgEoKiex3UubkSkV1zSE1BS6O4pXcaxcNtUlQsOmOmhVnDwIvqGRfEmuz83tIGL13cXMZn6upPyg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="searchTerm"> <button type="submit">Search</buton>
</form>
<div id="display-results">
</div>
```

I have broken down a lot of the smaller steps into their own function for ease of use ans trans portability.

Assuming that are getting an Array of Arrays returned from [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/), Then you want to use `$.each()`.

`.each()`

> **Description:** Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

`$.each()`

> **Description:** A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

> The `$.each()` function is not the same as `$(selector).each()`, which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The `$.each()` function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

That should help you identify which to use when.

It would behoove you to review the documentation for both jQuery and Papa Parse. You have a mix of JavaScript and jQuery in your example code, so I am assuming you have a great deal more hiding elsewhere. There is nothing wrong with this, yet it would be a better practice to homogenize your code to one or the other.